# How to print out non-contiguous columns in Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning, everyone!

I need to build a macro that will print out a report based on the current active worksheet. The worksheet contains several macro buttons, each of which will display different content within the same range of this particular sheet. And not all of the columns that I need to have in the reports, however, they can not be moved around. So now I wrote this to solve this problem.

```
Sub Macro111()

Dim PrintThis As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Reports").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Reports")
Set PrintThis = Union(.Range("G1:G" & LastRow), .Range("k1:L" & LastRow), .Range("Q1:Q" & LastRow), .Range("S1:T" & LastRow))
End With

PrintThis.PrintPreview


End Sub
```

However, it is running forever, and it print out the columns in separate pages. How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What about hiding everything you don't need?

Comment: @Raystafarian Hiding is not acceptable either.

Comment: why is @Raystafarian 's idea not acceptable? you would hide unwanted columns temporarily and then unhide them after the print out

Comment: @user3598756, you mean hide it using vba and unhide it after print out?

Comment: yes. the user wouldn't even notice it if you wrap all involved statements between `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: Ok, I will try that! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this line should be changed to: `LastRow = Sheets("Reports").Range("G" & Sheets("Reports").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` (with just `Rows.Count`, it'll use the active sheet.

Comment: @BruceWayne, thank you! However, I changed it to this code, i dont know why the macro running wouldn't stop, and it is printing many blank rows. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Please don't update your code - it confuses readers and makes the answer irrelevant. If you have another question, ask another question. Be sure to try to fix it on your own first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running your macro, run this first:

```
Sub RunMeFirst()
    Columns.Hidden = True
    Range("G:G, K:L, Q:Q, S:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

After running your macro, un-hide all columns.

Comment: Can you also check for me if there is anything wrong with the LastRow sentence, the code is now running non-stop, and print out more pages that it supposes to.

Comment: @JosephLin  Put a `MsgBox LastRow` after it is calculated.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it.

Comment: Thanks to @Raystafarian, too!